# Swift: Dequeueing CollectionViewCells with Image in Assets

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a chat app interface and my icon images disappear when I scroll up and down. I understand that this could be due to the dequeueing nature of the collection view cells. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613186/uitableviewcell-imageview-disappears-when-scrolling) on SO suggests that this can be solved by caching the images. However, in my application, my icon images are loaded in Assets and not downloaded from a URL.

My code so far:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatBubbleCollectionViewCell
    let item = messages[indexPath.item]
    
    if item.fromUserUID == fromUserUID {
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = .customPink
        cell.textView.text = item.message
        cell.textView.textColor = .white
        cell.imageTextView.textColor = .white
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor.isActive = true
        
        if let _ = item.imageUrl {
            cell.imageIconView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_photo_white")
        }
    } else {
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = .faintGray
        cell.textView.text = item.message
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.imageTextView.textColor = .darkGray
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor.isActive = false
        
        if let _ = item.imageUrl {
            cell.imageIconView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_photo_pink")
        }
    }
    
    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressOnImage))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1
    
    if let message = item.message {
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.constant = estimatedFrame(for: message).width + 11
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleHeightAnchor.isActive = false
        cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = true
        cell.textView.isHidden = false
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.removeGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    } else {
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.constant = 120
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleHeightAnchor.isActive = true
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.imageTextView.text = "Fetching..."
        
        if let imageReadReceipt = item.readReceipt {
            if imageReadReceipt {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageTextView.text = "Deleted"
                    cell.imageIconView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_visibility_off")
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                }
            } else {
                if let imageUrlString = item.imageUrl {
                    cell.messageImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrlString), completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else if let _ = image {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                                cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = false
                                cell.imageTextView.text = "Tap and hold to view"
                                cell.textView.isHidden = true
                                cell.imageContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

The cellForRow needs to do quite a few things which I doubt is a reason for the disappearing icon images. It will have to identify whether the message is received or sent (so that the bubble can be drawn on the left or right), or if the message is an image message or a text message.

The results are like this after doing various scrolls up and down:

Before scrolls:

[image]

After scrolling a few times:

[image]

One can observe that the deleteIcon image is gone with the "Deleted" text. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For one thing - when your async call finishes, you have to make sure that your cell is still displaying the same object before setting the image. Something like `guard cell.imageUrl == item.imageUrl else { return }`.

Comment: @Sulthan Not quite sure where do I implement that. Mind showing some code?